# PHP 'illegal offset'

Tags: php

I have a simple PHP blackjack script that I seem to be getting errors in.

The part of code causing the problem is this;

```
function evaluateHand($hand) {
    global $faces;
    $value = 0;
    foreach ($hand as $card) {
        if ($value > 11 && $card['face'] == 'a') {
            $value = $value + 1;
        }
        else {
            $value = intval($value) + intval($faces[$card['face']]); <----- error
        }
    }
    return $value;
}
```

The error is "Warning: Illegal offset 'face'" on the line I've pointed to above.

What's causing this? Or how I could fix it?

Comment: This isn't [the error I get](http://jsbin.com/makeregufa/1/edit?js,console). And that doesn't look like JavaScript. Are you sure you aren't writing PHP?

Comment: This isn't javascript

Comment: Could you add with which value you call this (PHP) function?

Comment: Here is a repl to see how this can happen in action https://repl.it/GlFZ/1

Answer (score 0):

`Illegal offset` means you are requesting an array key that doesn't exist. In this case, the array in `$card` has no key `face` when the error is thrown.